# SQL column reference "id" is ambiguous

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select, ambiguous

I tried the following select:

```sql
SELECT (id,name) FROM v_groups vg 
INNER JOIN people2v_groups p2vg ON vg.id = p2vg.v_group_id
WHERE p2vg.people_id =0;
```

And, I get the following error column reference `id` is ambiguous.

If I try the same `SELECT`, but I only ask for `name` and not for `id` also, it works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Once you have more than one table in your statement you should *alway* prefix your column names with the corresponding table alias. That way you'll never get this error.

Comment: This issue actually happens when there is same column name in both tables.
where <tableName.columnName> = <value> can solve this issue.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You need the table name/alias in the `SELECT` part (maybe `(vg.id, name)`) :

```
SELECT (vg.id, name)
FROM v_groups vg 
INNER JOIN people2v_groups p2vg
  ON vg.id = p2vg.v_group_id
WHERE p2vg.people_id = 0;
```

Answer (score 11):

I suppose your p2vg table has also an id field , in that case , postgres cannot find if the id in the `SELECT` refers to vg or p2vg.

you should use `SELECT(vg.id,vg.name)` to remove ambiguity

Comment: Yeah as the matter of fact the id field is duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT (vg.id, name) FROM v_groups vg 
INNER JOIN people2v_groups p2vg ON vg.id = p2vg.v_group_id
WHERE p2vg.people_id = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT vg.id, 
       vg.name
  FROM v_groups vg INNER JOIN  
       people2v_groups p2vg ON vg.id = p2vg.v_group_id
 WHERE p2vg.people_id = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

As a additional note: I got this error when I was using a CTE for a join resulting in an ambiguity. I was using the CTE in `FROM` with an alias and despite prefixing the `SELECT`ed column with the CTE's alias, postgres would still produce this error on the prefixed column call. It was a bit trickier to discover as my query was long.

Hope it helps someone out there.

Comment: what is the solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I created `person` table, then inserted 2 rows into it as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO person (id, name) 
VALUES (1, 'John'), (2, 'David');
```

Then, I created `my_func()` which returns `person` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(20))
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT id, name FROM person;
END;        -- ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Finally, calling `my_func()` got the same error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT id, name FROM person
               ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
QUERY:  SELECT id, name FROM person
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function my_func() line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

So, I set the table name `person` with `.` just before `id` and `name` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(20))
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT person.id, person.name FROM person;
END;               -- ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑    ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Finally, I could call `my_func()` without error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
  my_func
-----------
 (1,John)
 (2,David)
(2 rows)
```

*Memos:

- Omitting `FROM` clause from [SELECT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) gets [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975755/missing-from-clause-entry-for-a-table/77810473#77810473)
- If the number of the columns in `RETURNS TABLE(...)` doesn't match the number of the returned columns, there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70613079/number-of-returned-columns-does-not-match-expected-column-count-return-concat/77811663#77811663).