# postgresql return table ERROR: column reference is ambiguous

Tags: postgresql, return, ambiguous

I am trying to run a query in R to checked shared commenters between two different subreddits. However, I keep getting the following error:

> Warning: Error in postgresqlExecStatement: RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  column reference "subreddit" is ambiguous
>   )

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

```
query <- sprintf("
SELECT final.subreddit_a, final.subreddit_b 
FROM 
  (SELECT a.subreddit AS subreddit_a, 
          a.authors AS authors_in_sub_a, 
          b.subreddit AS subreddit_b, 
          b.authors AS authors_in_sub_b, 
          floor(100 * (count(*)/((a.authors + b.authors)/2))) AS percentage 
  FROM
    (SELECT t1.author AS author, 
            t1.subreddit AS subreddit, 
            t2.authors AS authors
    FROM 
      (SELECT DISTINCT author, subreddit 
      FROM %s 
      WHERE %s author!='[deleted]') AS t1
      JOIN 
        (SELECT * 
        FROM 
          (SELECT subreddit, count(distinct author) AS authors 
          FROM %s 
          WHERE %s author!='[deleted]' GROUP BY subreddit) AS t5 
          WHERE authors >= %s) AS t2
      ON t1.subreddit=t2.subreddit
      GROUP BY subreddit, author) AS a
    JOIN 
      (SELECT t3.author AS author, 
              t3.subreddit AS subreddit, 
              t4.authors AS authors
      FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT author, subreddit 
        FROM %s 
        WHERE %s author!='[deleted]') AS t3
        JOIN 
          (SELECT * 
          FROM 
            (SELECT subreddit, count(distinct author) AS authors 
            FROM %s 
            WHERE %s author!='[deleted]' GROUP BY subreddit) AS t6 
          WHERE authors >= %s) AS t4
        ON t3.subreddit=t4.subreddit
        GROUP BY subreddit, author) AS b
      ON a.author=b.author
    WHERE a.subreddit!=b.subreddit GROUP BY 1,3) AS final
  WHERE final.percentage > %s;"
```

Comment: It should be sufficient to qualify every use of subreddit field in a query with it's source. Now sometimes you do that (e.g. a.subreddit), but there are at least few uses without alias|table name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pgsql return table ERROR: column reference is ambiguous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750707/pgsql-return-table-error-column-reference-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1):

Write `table_name.subreddit` instead of `subreddit`.

Answer (score 1):

you should use alias on table name with long select query