# Number of returned columns does not match expected column count // Return concatinated row in plpgsql function

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create query: searching stats of persons by phone number.
I start using `INNER JOIN` in internal query and now I don't understand how type I must return.
I'm trying to use view as type, but they can't contain atributes with same name. Okay, I trim it to 3.
But I still get error and dont understand what it means:

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Number of returned columns (3) does not match expected column count (2).
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_fio_by_phone_number(bigint) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
SQL state: 42804
```

Code:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW persons_fios_and_telephons AS
  SELECT p.name, p.surname, pt.number
  FROM person p
  INNER JOIN persons_telefons pt on p.id = pt.person_id;
        
DROP FUNCTION get_fio_by_phone_number(bigint);
    
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_fio_by_phone_number(user_phone BIGINT) RETURNS SETOF persons_and_telephons
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
    SELECT *
    FROM persons_fios_and_telephons pat
    WHERE pat.number = get_fio_by_phone_number.user_phone;
      
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'There is no person with number "%".', user_phone;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    
SELECT * FROM get_fio_by_phone_number(89998887766)
```

Is there any way to make function without rough atributes enumeration? Thanks!

Comment: You are returning `SETOF persons_and_telephons` yet  doing: `SELECT *  FROM persons_fios_and_telephons pat ...`. Obviously  the table and view columns don't match. Change the `*` to a column list that matches `SETOF persons_and_telephons` or use `SETOF  persons_fios_and_telephons`.

Comment: Oh, bruh, i just inaccuratly renamed view. Thank you, buddy!

Answer (score 1):

I created `person` table, then inserted 2 rows into it as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  age INT
);

INSERT INTO person (id, name, age) 
VALUES (1, 'John', 27), (2, 'David', 32);
```

Then, I created `my_func()` which returns `person` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(id INT, name VARCHAR(20), age INT)
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT person.id, person.name FROM person;
END;        -- ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Finally, calling `my_func()` got the same error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Number of returned columns (2) does not match expected column count (3).
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT person.id, person.name FROM person"
PL/pgSQL function my_func() line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

So, I added `person.age` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TABLE(id INT, name VARCHAR(20), age INT)
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT person.id, person.name, person.age FROM person;
END;                                       -- ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Finally, I could call `my_func()` without error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# SELECT * FROM person;
   my_func
--------------
 (1,John,27)
 (2,David,32)
(2 rows)
```

*Memos:

- Omitting the table name `person` with `.` from `id`, `name` and `age` gets [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/sql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous/77811511#77811511).
- Omitting `FROM` clause from [SELECT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) gets [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975755/missing-from-clause-entry-for-a-table/77810473#77810473).