# It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin

I have a function in plpgsql:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION core.date_bs_from_ad(date_in_ad date)
RETURNS character varying AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT date_in_bs 
          FROM core.date_conversion
          WHERE date_in_ad = $1);
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It is created with no errors, but when I use this function it through following error:

```
ERROR:  column reference "date_in_ad" is ambiguous
LINE 3:   WHERE date_in_ad = $1
                ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
QUERY:  SELECT (
        SELECT MAX(date_in_bs) FROM core.date_conversion
        WHERE date_in_ad = $1
    )
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function core.date_bs_from_ad(date) line 3 at RETURN
********** Error **********

ERROR: column reference "date_in_ad" is ambiguous
SQL state: 42702
Detail: It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
Context: PL/pgSQL function core.date_bs_from_ad(date) line 3 at RETURN
```

Comment: The error messages says it all: you have a column *and* a parameter with the same name. You need to change the name of the parameter to avoid ambiguity

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, your comment should be an answer and not a comment. Pls post it as answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In cases like these, where the code is simple straightforward enough, sometimes it is useful to rely on one of these special plpgsql commands at the start of the function text:

```
#variable_conflict error
#variable_conflict use_variable
#variable_conflict use_column
```

In this case, it would be used as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION core.date_bs_from_ad(date_in_ad date)
  RETURNS character varying AS
$$
#variable_conflict use_column
BEGIN
    RETURN(
        SELECT date_in_bs FROM core.date_conversion
        WHERE date_in_ad = $1
    );
END
$$
```

This is especially useful for cases when the clash is not with the parameters, but rather with the output column names, such as this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION core.date_bs_from_ad(p_date_in_ad date)
  RETURNS TABLE (date_in_bs character varying) AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT date_in_bs FROM core.date_conversion
        WHERE date_in_ad = p_date_in_ad;
END;
$$
```

The function above will fail because it the compiler cannot decide if `date_in_bs` is the output variable name or one of `core.date_conversion`'s columns. For problems like these, the command `#variable_conflict use_column` can really help.

Answer (score 34):

There is a collision between SQL identifier and PlpgSQL variable. There are no clean, what do you want. You wrote a predicate, that is TRUE always.

Good to use:

- prefix (usually "_") for local variables
- qualified names in embedded SQL - like table_name.column_name

so both techniques (only one is necessary)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION core.date_bs_from_ad(_date_in_ad date)
RETURNS character varying AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN SELECT dc.date_in_bs
             FROM core.date_conversion dc
            WHERE dc.date_in_ad = _date_in_ad;
END
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For these one line functions is SQL language better:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION core.date_bs_from_ad(_date_in_ad date)
RETURNS character varying AS $$
   SELECT dc.date_in_bs
      FROM core.date_conversion dc
     WHERE dc.date_in_ad = $1; 
$$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Not a big fan of the `_` prefix myself - it's a bit hard to notice, and can be confusing when reading large amounts of code. I prefer a more noticeable prefix, like `p_`. (Regardless, the answer is correct, of course).

Comment: Hungarian convention has no sense here. But good naming is important. Smart naming for PK and FK can simplify writing and reading queries.

Comment: A clean API does not munge parameter names, that's why this practice of renaming params to avoid conflicts is in fact a bad practice. It's better to use qualified names in pl/pgsql code.

Answer (score 1):

Another option not mentioned in the other answers is prefixing the function name `core.date_bs_from_ad` to the column name `date_in_ad` so that you get `core.date_bs_from_ad.date_in_ad`.

The specifics of this question make it clear that using one of the other answers is the correct choice for the individual who asked the question but this is a valid and missing answer based on the title of the question.

I was brought here by google and didn't find this option mentioned and in my case prefixing the function name was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I created `test` table, then inserted the row whose `num` is `0` into it as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  num INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (0);
```

Then, I ran the [DO statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) below to increment `num` by 1:

```sql
DO $$DECLARE num INTEGER := 2;
BEGIN
  UPDATE test SET num = num + 1;
END
$$;
```

But I got the same error below:

```sql
ERROR:  column reference "num" is ambiguous
LINE 1: UPDATE test SET num = num + 1
                              ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
QUERY:  UPDATE test SET num = num + 1
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 4 at SQL statement
```

So, I removed `DECLARE` clause as shown below, then I could run the `DO` statement without error:

```sql
DO $$/*DECLARE num INTEGER := 2;*/
BEGIN
  UPDATE test SET num = num + 1;
END
$$;
```