# Ambiguous column reference - it could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am getting the following error in PostgreSQL:

> [42702] ERROR: column reference "topicid" is ambiguous Detail: It
> could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column. Where:
> PL/pgSQL function topics(integer) line 3 at RETURN QUERY

I understand that to mean there is a parameter and a table column with the same name. Except that I cannot see where it is because the only parameter I have is `_typeid` and not `topicid`.

Where is the problem exactly in this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION topics(_typeid integer DEFAULT NULL::integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(topicid integer, typeid integer, topic character varying)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY SELECT
    topicid
     ,typeid
     ,topic
FROM
    topic
WHERE
    _typeid IS NULL
   OR
        typeID = _typeid
ORDER BY
    topic ASC;
END
$$;
```

If I refactor it to just use `sql` then it works fine like such:

```
CREATE FUNCTION topics(_typeid integer DEFAULT NULL::integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(topicid integer, typeid integer, topic character varying)
  LANGUAGE sql
AS
$$
SELECT
    topicid
     ,typeid
     ,topic
FROM
    topic
WHERE
    _typeid IS NULL
   OR
        typeID = _typeid
ORDER BY
    topic ASC;
$$;
```

Comment: Duplicate of [It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662295/it-could-refer-to-either-a-pl-pgsql-variable-or-a-table-column).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Comment: @TylerH No that is a different question. This has already been answered below by Adrian Klaver.

Comment: It is literally the same problem and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conflict is between the variables in `RETURNS TABLE` and the field names returned from the query. Table qualify the field names in the query e.g. `topic.topicid, topic.typid, topic.topic`.

Comment: Why does it not have any problem when the language is plain `sql`?

Comment: The short answer is that the `plpgsql` parser is stricter. The longer answer can be found here [Implementation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-implementation.html). This section also includes ways to override the behavior in various ways.  I found it easier just to get used to making the columns and variables unambiguous to begin with.