# Single search box produces "ERROR: column reference "name" is ambiguous"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, search, join

I am trying to use a single search field to filter any column following [Railscasts 240](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax). The key piece for defining the search function is in the Contact model.

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      joins(:school).where(['name ILIKE ? OR email ILIKE ? OR school.name ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
    else
      all
    end
  end
```

This works without the join and school.name. Contact belongs to school and has a school_id column. The exact error is:

```
PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "name" is ambiguous
```

I'm guessing the ambiguous error is because I am trying to search both contact.name and school.name. Looking for a suggestion to allow searching both without adding another search field or needing the user to specify the search type.

**Edit:**

Good suggestions below to use contact.name to deal with the ambiguity, but that leads to another error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "contact"
LINE 1: ...ON "schools"."id" = "contacts"."school_id" WHERE (contact.na...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "contacts".* FROM "contacts" INNER JOIN "schools" ON "schools"."id" = "contacts"."school_id" WHERE (contact.name ILIKE '%joseph%' OR email ILIKE '%joseph%' OR school.name ILIKE '%joseph%')  ORDER BY name asc LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

I thought this was due to the inner join moving the entire query into the schools table, but the error persists even if I remove the other two queries and ONLY search on school.name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ambiguous errors is caused by PG not knowing which `name` column the query reffers to - `contacts.name` or `schools.name`. You can fix it by changing your query to:

```
joins(:school).where(['contacts.name ILIKE ? OR email ILIKE ? OR schools.name ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
```

Comment: This suggestion works but produces another error. Please see above.

Comment: Table storing data for Contact model is named `contacts`, not `contact`. Please refer the sql query string returned with the error message: SELECT  "contacts".* FROM "**contacts**" INNER JOIN "schools" ON "schools"."id" = "contacts"."school_id" WHERE (**contact**.name ILIKE etc.

Comment: Definitely should have read more closely. This is interesting because the ruby syntax would be contact.name or contact.school.name. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if columns that same names is more then must add alias

try this, i add `contacts.name`

```
 def self.search(search)
    if search
      joins(:school).where(['contacts.name ILIKE ? OR email ILIKE ? school.name ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
    else
      all
    end
  end
```

Comment: This suggestion works but produces another error. Please see above.