# Why I am getting "column reference *** is ambiguous"?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

This query runs perfectly well on postgress and returns 2 columns that I am looking for:

```
SELECT  w.jobnr, w.ordernr
FROM
    (SELECT jobnr, ordernr FROM userdata.WIP_Data WHERE Year=2015 AND period=1) AS W
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT jobnr, ordernr FROM userdata.WIP_Data WHERE Year=2015 AND period=2) AS P 
    ON W.Jobnr=P.Jobnr;
```

It returns:
[image]

But when I enclose this query in a function as under:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION userdata.test3()
 RETURNS TABLE(jobnr character varying, ordernr character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT  w.jobnr, w.ordernr
    FROM
        (SELECT jobnr, ordernr FROM userdata.WIP_Data WHERE Year=2015 AND period=1) AS W

        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT jobnr, ordernr FROM userdata.WIP_Data WHERE Year=2015 AND period=2) AS P 
        ON W.Jobnr=P.Jobnr;
END; 
$function$
```

and execute it by `SELECT * from userdata.test3()`
I am getting following error:

```
ErrorCode: -2147467259
Severity: ERROR, Code: 42702, Line: 1076, Position:
ErrorMessage: column reference "jobnr" is ambiguous
Detail: It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
```

Any idea what is wrong here and how can I resolve it? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/sql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE),

> 38.5.10. SQL Functions Returning TABLE
>
> There is another way to declare a function as returning a set, which
> is to use the syntax RETURNS TABLE(columns). This is equivalent to
> using one or more OUT parameters plus marking the function as
> returning SETOF record (or SETOF a single output parameter's type, as
> appropriate). This notation is specified in recent versions of the SQL
> standard, and thus may be more portable than using SETOF.

That means when you declare the function with `RETURNS TABLE(jobnr character varying...`, `jobnr` is an out parameter. Thus `SELECT jobnr ...` is ambiguous.

Try declaring the function with aliases for the tables in your select:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION userdata.test3()
 RETURNS TABLE(jobnr character varying, ordernr character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT  w.jobnr, w.ordernr
    FROM
        (SELECT wip.jobnr, wip.ordernr FROM userdata.WIP_Data as wip WHERE Year=2015 AND period=1) AS W

        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT wip.jobnr, wip.ordernr FROM userdata.WIP_Data as wip WHERE Year=2015 AND period=2) AS P 
        ON W.Jobnr=P.Jobnr;
END; 
$function$
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same thing even though I used an alias as suggested here..?

Comment: @Luffydude, I suggest distilling the error down to a mcve (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and posting it as a question. I'd be glad to take a look

Answer (score 2):

May be a `bug` confusing the returning clausule

```
 RETURNS TABLE(jobnr character varying, ordernr character varying)
```

with a parameter declaration.

I know than jobnr is not a parameter (it is a column name of the returned recordset). But aperars to be that Postgres is confused about it.

Try it with others names in the `RETURNS` clausule

### Is not a bug, it's a feature

@Andreas is right! But this is a nonsense feature.

Comment: Thanks @Emilio Platzer, your answer is a way to bypass such issues but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I don't have the luxury of changing table columns or returning field names as this function needs to work for existing huge application. Andreas solution best suites my requirements.

Comment: Thank you Emilio! this was exactly the issue in my case. I was aliasing in my cte's a table as 'm', but in my returns table it was (m milestone).
so it was throwing the error. m.id is ambiguous. I was so confused, because I was very confident my actual sql code was running right. So thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who, like me, did not have the option to use table identifiers to distinguish columns from the ones in the `RETURNS` clause, switching the function's `LANGUAGE` from `plpgsql` to `sql` (and adapting the queries to that change) removed this ""feature"".

In my specific case, the conflict was with the express naming of columns on a `RETURNING` after an `INSERT`

I would like a solution that works while staying in `plpgsql`, but have not found it.