# Error: column reference is ambiguous

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I have two tables from which i want to get the date without using joins.

```
id ProductVersion   productName  productDate
1    p1.1            product1     2017-3-11
2    p1.2            product1     2017-3-11
3    p2.1            product2     2017-5-12
4    p2.2            product2     2017-5-12
5    p2.3            product2     2017-5-12
6    p3.1            product3     2017-11-21
7    p3.1            product3     2017-11-21
```

Table2

```
tid  productVersion  comments status       AvailableDate
101    p1.1            Good     Sold          2017-3-11  
102    p1.1            Good     Available     2017-3-12
1009   p1.1            Good     Available     2017-3-12
4008   p3.1            Average  NA            2017-11-11
106    p3.2            Good     Sold          2017-5-14
6      p3.1            Average  Available     2017-11-12
```

I have two tables as shown above.

I want to get productVersion,productName,productDate,Comments,status column details from the above two tables.

SQL Query(without joins):

```
select productversion t1,productName t1,productDate t1,comments t2,status t2 from table1 t1,table2 t2 
where t1.productVersion = t2.productversion
```

Error message:

```
Error: column reference "productDate" is ambiguous.
```

Any inputs?

Comment: `select productversion t1,productName t1,productDate t1,comments t2,status t2` - Why do you assign identical column aliases to multiple colums? Why are they identical to the table aliases? - Did you mean to write `select t1.productversion, t1.productName, t1.productDate, t2.comments, t2.status`?

Comment: You have tagged Oracle and PostgreSQL - these are two different RDBMS. which are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 3):

[TL;DR] Your main issue is that you appear to be putting the table aliases after the column name where an alias for the column is expected when they should be prefixing the column name to identify which table the columns belong to.

Your query is equivalent to:

```
select productversion AS columnalias1,
       productName    AS columnalias2,
       productDate    AS columnalias3,
       comments       AS columnalias4,
       status         AS columnalias5
from   table1 t1,
       table2 t2 
where  t1.productVersion = t2.productversion
```

And all your column aliases are either `t1` or `t2` so you will get multiple columns with the same name. I do not think this is what you intended as both tables have a `productVersion` column so the query parser does not know which you intended to use. You probably want the table aliases before the column name to identify which table each column is from:

```
select t1.productversion,
       t1.productName,
       t1.productDate,
       t2.comments,
       t2.status
from   table1 t1,
       table2 t2 
where  t1.productVersion = t2.productversion
```

The second problem is that, while you say it is a query "without joins", you are using a legacy Oracle comma-join syntax and your query can be rewritten to have exactly the same functionality using ANSI/ISO SQL syntax and is equivalent to:

```
select t1.productversion,
       t1.productName,
       t1.productDate,
       t2.comments,
       t2.status
from   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2 
       ON ( t1.productVersion = t2.productversion )
```

If you want something without joins then use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT productVersion,
       productName,
       productDate,
       NULL AS Comments,
       NULL AS status
FROM   table1
UNION ALL
SELECT productVersion,
       NULL AS productName,
       NULL AS productDate,
       Comments,
       status
FROM   table2
```

But it will not correlate the values in the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

To refer to a specific table column, you use this syntax:

```
table_name.column_name
```

Your query should be:

```
select t1.productversion, t1.productName, t1.productDate,
       t2.comments, t2.status
from table1 as t1
join table2 as t2 on t1.productVersion = t2.productversion
```