# Postgres column reference ambiguous when qualified with table name

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is a moderately complicated CTE that updates a number of tables depending on the content of a JSON argument.  When executing this function,
Postgres throws a `column reference "explode" is ambiguous` error.  The line the error is referring to actually has a table name qualifying the column reference.

I'm pretty sure I'm right about which line is causing the problem as if I remove the line I've marked below, the error disappears.

I've been trying to figure this one out some time and I have no idea.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prd.update_composition (json, OUT result json) AS
$$
BEGIN
  -- Update and return the new composition
  WITH composition AS (
    UPDATE prd.composition SET (
      explode
    ) = (
      payload_composition.explode
    )
    FROM json_to_record($1) AS payload_composition (
      id      integer,
      explode boolean
    )
    WHERE id IS NOT NULL
    RETURNING *
  ), payload_component AS (
    SELECT
      composition.composition_id,
      component."productId" AS product_id,
      component.quantity,
      component.removed
    FROM json_to_recordset($1->'components') AS component (
      "productId" integer,
      quantity    numeric(10,3),
      removed     boolean
    )
    CROSS JOIN composition
  ), updated_component AS (
    UPDATE prd.component existing SET (
      product_id,
      quantity
    ) = (
      component.product_id,
      component.quantity
    )
    FROM (
      SELECT
        composition_id,
        product_id,
        quantity
      FROM payload_component
      WHERE removed IS NOT TRUE
    ) component
    WHERE existing.composition_id = component.composition_id
    RETURNING *
  ), deleted AS (
    DELETE FROM prd.component existing
    USING (
      SELECT
        composition_id,
        product_id
      FROM payload_component
      WHERE removed IS TRUE
    ) payload_deleted
    WHERE existing.composition_id = payload_deleted.composition_id
      AND existing.product_id = payload_deleted.product_id
  )
  SELECT json_strip_nulls(to_json(r)) INTO result
  FROM (
    SELECT
      composition.composition_id,
      composition.explode -- HERE IS THE OFFENDING LINE --
    FROM composition
  ) r;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Why is there an `ambiguous column reference error` with this code?

Comment: Could you show us the full error, please, complete with line numbers?

Comment: The problem is to in the line you marked it is in your CTE, because there the `explode` column *is not* qualified with a table name. Here: `UPDATE prd.composition SET ( --> explode <-- ) = ( payload_composition.explode ) FROM json_to_record($1) AS payload_composition (  id integer, explode boolean )` It does not know where to get this column from.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yep. The returning clause needed a clean up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/sql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the `RETURNING` clause in the `composition` CTE.

By using the `*` with `RETURNING` it returns all columns from all tables in the `from_list`.

The returning clause should specify which columns and from which tables to return,
especially if there are multiple tables in the `from_list`.

In this case, an alias should be used in the `INSERT` to reference the required
columns:

```
WITH composition AS (
    UPDATE prd.composition c SET ( -- See here
      explode
    ) = (
      payload_composition.explode
    )
    FROM json_to_record($1) AS payload_composition (
      id      integer,
      explode boolean
    )
    WHERE id IS NOT NULL
    RETURNING c.* -- and here
  )
```