# Column reference "id" is ambiguous - It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have this simple test function in Postgres (in my `test` schema).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.func_001
(
par_id int
)
RETURNS TABLE
(
id int
)

AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

    var_id int;

BEGIN

    update test.item    --- this is a table 
    set 
    id = 4
    WHERE
    id = 44;

return query 
select 1000 as id;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE  plpgsql;
```

The `test.item` table has a single id column.

I get the error below while trying to run the function.

```
Query execution failed

Reason:
SQL Error [42702]: ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous
  Detail: It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function test.func_001(integer) line 8 at SQL statement
```

This error seems weird, does it mean that Postgres is finding a conflict/clash between the `test.item.id` column and the `id` column from the returned table?! 
How come? This doesn't make any sense.

I cannot believe this but I see no other id usages here.

Note that if I comment out just this part.

```
-- WHERE
-- id = 44;
```

then suddenly the function works fine.

So it seems Postgres is confusing the id in the where 
clause with something else that's named id?!

With what?

This is totally illogical and counter-intuitive.

Could someone please explain?

Comment: I guess you get the error, because you have a return value named id and a column in your table with the same name

Comment: Well, OK... I don't quite have a return value `id`. I am returning a table (from this function) and that returned table has an id column. Also, I have a physical table (`test.item`) which has an `id` column. I am amazed why it is finding a clash between the two. Makes no sense to me. Note that I have read the full manual about PL/pgSQL, its syntax, etc. There is nothing there documenting this weird behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clause `FUNCTION fx() RETURNS TABLE(x int, y int, ...)` is same like `FUNCTION(OUT x int, OUT y int) RETURNS SETOF record`. So in your case, there is implicit variable `id`, although you don't use it explicitly.

PostgreSQL design allows to produce rows without SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(a int)
RETURNS TABLE(b int, c int) AS $$
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..a
  LOOP
    b := i; c := i * 10;
    RETURN NEXT;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

See [following](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET) document, please.

> There is another way to declare a function as returning a set, which is to use the syntax RETURNS TABLE(columns). This is equivalent to using one or more OUT parameters plus marking the function as returning SETOF record (or SETOF a single output parameter's type, as appropriate). This notation is specified in recent versions of the SQL standard, and thus may be more portable than using SETOF.

Answer (score 2):

There is a name conflict between the variable `id` that is defined by the `RETURNS TABLE` clause and the column of the same name.

Things like that cause problems in all programming languages, only PostgreSQL is nice enough to alert you rather than doing something that may not be what you intended.

Qualify the column reference like this to remove the ambiguity:

```
WHERE test.item.id = 44
```

Comment: Well, if I had a local (function level) variable, I would understand this error but not in this case... So you're saying that the `id` in `RETURNS TABLE(id int)` under the hood is just implemented as a variable? And that's why Postgres is saying that I have an ambiguity?

Comment: "Things like that cause problems in all programming languages, only PostgreSQL is nice enough to alert you..." That's kind of exaggerated btw.

Comment: I don't think `id` in the column list of the return table should clash with variables and column names of other tables. That doesn't sound normal, not for 2018. But anyway, thanks, I will qualify my column names as you suggest.

Comment: It is less exaggerated than what you originally had in your question. And I think it is true.

Comment: Your way of boldly stating that everything you don't understand is backwards gives me the impression that you don't have a lot of programming experience.

Comment: It's not that I don't understand it, now that you mentioned "the id variable" it's completely clear to me. I see you're a contributor to Postgres which is good. Make a survey and ask some people if they like "this feature". I am not sure about Oracle but in SQL Server one does not have this particular issue (maybe because they have @ for variable names). Never mind. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No offense taken. [The fine manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html) says: *When a PL/pgSQL function is declared with output parameters, the output parameters are given $n names and optional aliases in just the same way as the normal input parameters. An output parameter is effectively a variable that starts out NULL; it should be assigned to during the execution of the function. The final value of the parameter is what is returned.*

Comment: @peter.petrov - T-SQL (SQL Server) is strongly different than Oracle, or Postgres. It is life. I believe so PLpgSQL or PL/SQL (Oracle) is significantly better than T-SQL - but it is my believe - What is true - it has different design, and start after T-SQL experience can be difficult.

Comment: Thanks again. Any idea why it says the error is at line 8? Line 8 counted from where?

Comment: Line 1 is the line with the opening `$BODY$`. Line 8 is where the SQL statement with the error starts.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.