# Invalid operation: column reference "column_name" is ambiguous PostgreSql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to change the text from `google.com` in to `google` in my column `domain` when I am creating a view in Redshift Postgres DB but I am getting an error:

> Invalid operation: column reference "domain" is ambiguous

My code is:

```
CASE 
   WHEN domain = 'goolge.com' THEN 'google' 
   ELSE domain 
END as domain,
```

How could I be able to solve this out?

Comment: Can you paste the whole query?

Comment: Qualify the columns, i.e. specify the table too. Like `table1.domain`.

Comment: It's a 150 line view with dependencies on other views. I assume the problem is that I have used the `domain` above in the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/sql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get the error if you had multiple table references in your `from` clause.  For instance, if both `a` and `b` have `domain`, then this will generate the error:

```
select domain
from a join
     b
     using (whatever);
```

The solution is to get in the habit of ALWAYS qualifying column names in a query.  Then you will never have this issue:

```
select a.domain
from a join
     b
     using (whatever);
```