# Need help on ambiguous column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(
    sid int PRIMARY KEY,
    sname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    saddress varchar(20) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE COURSE
(
    cid int PRIMARY KEY,
    cname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    ccredit int NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE REGISTER
(
    eid int PRIMARY KEY,
    sid int NOT NULL,
    cid int NOT NULL,
    edate date NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES STUDENT (sid) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES COURSE (cid) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

But when I want to show the full details of student who registered a 'Database' subject, I get the following error:

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Ambiguous column name 'sid'
>
> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Ambiguous column name 'cid'

Here is the query code, can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT eid, edate, cname, sname, saddress, sid, cid
FROM register r
JOIN course c ON c.cid = r.cid
JOIN student s ON r.sid = s.sid
WHERE cname = 'database';
```

Comment: It's good programming practice to always qualify all columns, at least when several tables are involved. Just like `r.sid` instead of just `sid`.

Comment: Okay I will try to practice this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/sql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those column names exist in more than one of the tables from which you're selecting data, so the query engine doesn't know which table you want to use.  You can specify it manually in the `SELECT` clause by prepending the table (or alias) name:

```
SELECT
  eid,
  edate,
  cname,
  sname,
  saddress,
  s.sid,
  c.cid
FROM register r
JOIN course c ON c.cid = r.cid
JOIN student s ON r.sid = s.sid
WHERE cname = 'database'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a column named cid in both the register and course tables. The error is simply stating that the parser doesn't know which column you want. you need to prefix the column name in your select statement with the proper alias. `r.cid` for register table or `c.cid` for the course table