# column reference "group_id" is ambiguous when join

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, join

I have some troubles with join two tables:

Groups: group_id, group_name

Students: student_id, group_id, first_name, last_name

I wanna count how many students have each group and then output group name, but when i write like this:

```
public String findGroupsByStudentsNumber(int expectedStudentsNumber) {
        return " SELECT group_id, COUNT(student_id) AS Number_of_students " +
                "FROM students " +
                "LEFT JOIN groups ON group_id = groups.group_id " +
                "GROUP BY group_id " +
                "HAVING Number_of_students <=" + expectedStudentsNumber +
                " ORDER BY group_id";
    }
```

there is an error "column reference "group_id" is ambiguous".

Comment: you are missing alias name for student table

Comment: Its always good practice to use alias for your table name and specially when you have common column name to distinguish which table column you are referring to.

Comment: Why are you joining to the groups table at all?  It doesn't seem to contribute anything to your result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both tables have a `group_id` column, you can't have a plain `group_id` in your query without specifying which one you're referring to. This is one way it could look:

```sql
SELECT students.group_id, COUNT(student_id) AS Number_of_students
FROM students
LEFT JOIN groups ON students.group_id = groups.group_id
GROUP BY students.group_id 
HAVING Number_of_students <= X
ORDER BY students.group_id
```

Comment: @BingeEater . . . This is not a good example of coding.  The aggregation should be on `groups.group_id` because that is (presumably) the primary key of `groups`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The aggregation could equally be on `students.group_id` or `groups.group_id` with the same results, because of the equality in the join condition. Honestly, it's the join itself which is unnecessary - if there's only one group per `group_id`, then the groups table isn't adding anything to this query.

Comment: @Tamirllan . . . I'm not sure if Postgres is smart enough to make use of a primary key index when it is on the *right* side of a `left join`.  The optimize is smart, but that would take real smarts.