# What is this "ERROR: ambiguous column reference error"?

Tags: postgresql

I want to fill an empty field of table 1 with values ​​that I find by the code from table 1, in table 2

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.add_soate(
 )
    RETURNS SETOF zagsmarriagelist 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
    
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    r zagsmarriagelist%rowtype;
DECLARE code varchar;
BEGIN

  FOR r IN
   SELECT id FROM zagsmarriagelist
  LOOP
    code := (select nullif(regexp_replace(r::varchar, '\D','','g'), ''));
   UPDATE zagsmarriagelist
   SET bridesoate = (select substring(a.code from 1 for 14) from ate_history a where a.ate::varchar=(select bridebirthaddress from zagsmarriagelist where id::varchar=code))
           WHERE id::varchar=code;
   RETURN NEXT r;
 END LOOP;
 RETURN;
END
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.add_soate()
    OWNER TO postgres;
  
select * from add_soate();
```

displays an error:

> ERROR: ERROR: ambiguous reference to column "code" LINE 2: ... ess
> from zagsmarriagelist z where z.id::varchar = code)) as ... ^ DETAIL:
> Assumes a reference to a PL / pgSQL variable or table column. QUERY:
> UPDATE zagsmarriagelist SET bridesoate = (case when (select
> z.bridebirthaddress from zagsmarriagelist z where z.id::varchar =
> code)! = '' Then cast ((select substring (a.code from 1 for 14) from
> ate_history a where a.ate :: varchar = (select z.bridebirthaddress
> from zagsmarriagelist z where z.id::varchar = code)) as integer) else
> NULL END), groomsoate = (case when (select z.groombirthaddress from
> zagsmarriagelist z where z.id::varchar = code)! = '' then cast
> ((select substring (a.code from 1 for 14) from ate_history a where
> a.ate: : varchar = (select z.bridebirthaddress from zagsmarriagelist z
> where z.id::varchar = code)) as integer) else NULL END) WHERE
> zagsmarriagelist.id::varchar=code CONTEXT: PL / pgSQL add_soate ()
> function, line 13, statement SQL statement

why doesn't it recognize the variable 'code' in the subquery?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand, but I think you can get rid of the whole looping and over complicated sub-query, and write that with a single UPDATE statement. Something like this: https://pastebin.com/5v6xBW8R

Comment: I am not sure what your intention behind the regexp_replace is, but I think it comes from a misunderstanding on what `r` contains. You probably just want: `code := r.id;`

Comment: God, I'm so stupid, I didn't even think about this solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
where id::varchar = code
```

because `ate_history` has a column called `code` *and* you defined a variable `code`, so it's ambiguous as to which one the expression refers to, as both are in scope.

Normally you would just must qualify it, but you can't so just rename it uniquely.

```
declare _code

_code := (select nullif(regexp_replace(r::varchar, '\D','','g'), ''));

where id::varchar = _code
```

or if you wanted the column from `ate_history`:

```
where id::varchar = a.code
```