# How to deal with ambiguous column reference in sql column name reference?

Tags: sql, join, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have some code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW cctv_join_1  
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM cctv1_details AS A 
    LFET JOIN cctv3_details AS B ON (A.CDE_WR = B.CDE_WR) AND A.CDE_dist = B.CDE_dist
```

I then try

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW cctv_join_2  
AS
   (SELECT * 
    FROM cctv_join_1 AS A
    LEFT JOIN cctv5_details AS B ON (A.CDE_WR = B.CDE_WR) AND (A.CDE_dist = B.CDE_dist))
```

but I get an error

> Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Reference 'A.CDE_WR' is ambiguous, could be: A.CDE_WR, A.CDE_WR.; line 6 pos 4

in databricks. How can I deal with this?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Try select a.*, b.* but we always name our fields explicitly to help people read what we're doing. Also, will it work if you reuse the same aliases across your selections? Can you try using D and E in the second statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cctv1_details c1d LEFT JOIN
     cctv3_details c3d
     ON c1d.CDE_WR = c3d.CDE_WR AND c1d.CDE_dist = c3d.CDE_dist
```

is using `SELECT *`.  The `*` is shorthand for *all* columns from both tables.

Obviously the combined columns from the two tables have duplicate column names; at least, `CDE_WR` and `CDE_dist` -- and there may be others.  The general solution is to list all the columns out:

```
SELECT c1d.col1, c1d.col2, . . . c3d.colx, c3d.coly
FROM cctv1_details c1d LEFT JOIN
     cctv3_details c3d
     ON c1d.CDE_WR = c3d.CDE_WR AND c1d.CDE_dist = c3d.CDE_dist;
```

However, this is often shorted to:

```
SELECT c1d.*, c3d.colx, c3d.coly
FROM cctv1_details c1d LEFT JOIN
     cctv3_details c3d
     ON c1d.CDE_WR = c3d.CDE_WR AND c1d.CDE_dist = c3d.CDE_dist;
```

Note that I changed the table aliases to be reasonable abbreviations for the table names, making the query much clearer and easier to maintain.