# How to solve ambiguous column name in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I run the below SQL query and get this error: `Errors: Ambiguous column name 'EmailAddress'.`

Have tried to use `select R.EmailAddress...`, but it got me the same error.
Without the Join the query works well.

what am I missing?

```
select EmailAddress, [Order Number], order_date, rank,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_date, EmailAddress ORDER BY order_date DESC) AS rankDate,
R.firstname as 'FirstName',R.lastname as 'LastName', 'IL' as 'Locale'

from( 

    select
    O.FirstName, O.LastName, O.email as 'EmailAddress',
    O.order_number as 'Order Number',O.order_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY O.email ORDER BY O.order_date DESC) AS rank,
    O.order_number as 'Order Number Compare' 
    from [TEST ORDER] O
    where O.order_date>='12/27/2020' and O.email is not null 
) as R


join [All Blend Subscribers] as ABS
on R.EmailAddress = ABS.emailAddress
```

Comment: First, stop cramming all your code together. Use white space to make your code readable. Second, it is best practice to give every table a short but not cryptic alias and to use those aliases for EVERY column reference (not just some). You refer to emailaddress in your select list TWICE - did you notice? Lastly, use a date literal format that is unambiguous.

Comment: Qualify *all* column references!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your need to tell SQL server what `EmailAddress` want to get from tables on `SELECT` part, there are two kind of `EmailAddress` from your query.

```
select R.EmailAddress, [Order Number], order_date, rank,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_date, R.EmailAddress ORDER BY order_date DESC) AS rankDate,
R.firstname as 'FirstName',R.lastname as 'LastName', 'IL' as 'Locale'
from( 

    select
    O.FirstName, O.LastName, O.email as 'EmailAddress',
    O.order_number as 'Order Number',O.order_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY O.email ORDER BY O.order_date DESC) AS rank,
    O.order_number as 'Order Number Compare' 
    from [TEST ORDER] O
    where O.order_date>='12/27/2020' and O.email is not null 
) as R
join [All Blend Subscribers] as ABS
on R.EmailAddress = ABS.emailAddress
```

> I would get columns by an alias clearly because it can avoid ambiguous error.

Comment: thank you! I missed out on the second `EmailAddress ` in the PARTITION.