# Why postgres trigger function returns some columns reference is ambiguous?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.5

I have two tables:
Source table where I insert or update value

```
CREATE TABLE test.table_1
(
    id smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('test.table_1_id_seq'::regclass),
    sub_id smallint,
    value numeric(5,5)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE test.table_1
    OWNER to postgres;
```

I need to get difference between NEW and OLD value and add it to `sum_value` in `table_1_sum` on update.
Or need to insert new row if `id` and `sub_id` already exists in `table_1_sum`

```
CREATE TABLE test.table_1_sum
(
    id smallint,
    sub_id smallint,
    sum_value numeric(5,5),
    CONSTRAINT unq_constraint UNIQUE (id, sub_id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE test.table_1_sum
    OWNER to postgres;
```

I made a function with trigger to do this

```
CREATE FUNCTION test.add_diff()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
        delta_value   numeric;      
    BEGIN      
        IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN            
            delta_value = NEW.value - OLD.value;        
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN       
            delta_value = NEW.value;        
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN       
            delta_value = -1 * OLD.value;       
        END IF;         
            INSERT INTO test.table_1_sum (
                sub_id,
                sum_value
                )
            VALUES (
                NEW.sub_id,
                NEW.value               
               )
                ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT unq_constraint
                DO UPDATE 
                    SET 
                    sum_value = sum_value + delta_value;    
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$BODY$;
ALTER FUNCTION test.add_diff()
    OWNER TO postgres;
    
    
CREATE TRIGGER add_value_diff
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE 
    ON test.table_1
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.add_diff();
```

It does not work. I have no idea why.

It returns an error:

`ERROR:  column reference "sum_value" is ambiguous`
`LINE 13:      sum_value = sum_value + delta_value`

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/sql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=50bcaac7deda2490c370cd6bb12a64dc)

You have to explicitly reference `table_1_sum` in the calculation:

```
sum_value = table_1_sum.sum_value + delta_value;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is "virtual" table named `EXCLUDED` that holds an row with values that should be inserted (when `INSERT` has `ON CONFLICT DO` clause). This virtual table has same structure (same columns) like target table, so the just name of column is not unique.

You can read more details in related Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).