# pq: column reference "deleted_at" is ambiguous

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am generating my query dynamically And this is something I have before passing parameters and getting this error  `pq: column reference "deleted_at" is ambiguous`

**My query is**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM issues i
JOIN vehicles v ON (v.id = i.vehicle_id)
WHERE i.asset_owner_id = :asset_owner_id AND deleted_at IS NULL
  AND i.added_at >= :from AND i.added_at < :to AND i.status IN (:status)
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, you need to specify table i or v for the deleted_at column.

Comment: Is that column in both your tables issues and vehicles?  you just need to use the alias for what table you want for the AND deleted_at is in

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `deleted_at` in both tables.  That is what "ambiguous" means here.

Qualify *all* column references when you write a query.  I don't know which you intend, but something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM issues i JOIN
     vehicles v
     ON v.id = i.vehicle_id
WHERE i.asset_owner_id = :asset_owner_id AND
      i.deleted_at IS NULL AND
------^
      i.added_at >= :from AND
      i.added_at < :to AND
      i.status IN (:status);
```