# Column reference is NOT ambiguous

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are many threads on

> column reference "something" is ambiguous

This is typical in most RDBMS when more than one tables involved have the same column name. However, all my tables have an unique prefix for their own columns therefore no any columns in the schema would share the same name. Reason being is in a big query, it's easy to know where a column is from! For example `productid` in `order` table is `odrproductid`, and in `product` table is `pdtproductid`, so this query ran perfectly in pgAdmin query tool:

```
select pdtproductid
from orders
join product on odrproductid = pdtproductid and ...
```

Paste into a function and call this function.

> ```
> ERROR:  column reference "odrproductid" is ambiguous
> LINE 3:  join product on odrproductid = ...
>                          ^
> DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table
> column.
> ```

Obviously it can be resolved by adding alias and prefix columns in JOIN. But there is no variables defined in the function, and if it ran perfect interactively why not in the function? And added an alias for `orders`, it will pick `pdtproductid` and so on. If it's really an ambiguous column, logically it should have picked up from the up-front `SELECT` list.

**Solution**, paste the exact good sql into a variable and run it as dynamic SQL, it goes well. For example

```
AS $BODY$
declare pgsql text ;
begin 
  pgsql := 'select ... from orders join product on odrproductid = pdtproductid and ...';
  return query execute pgsql;
end;
```

Comment: Does your function have a parameter named `odrproductid`?

Comment: Except in `RETURNS TABLE(odrproductid ...)`

Comment: `order` is keyword? Maybe `select pdtproductid
from "order" join product on ...`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda It's an example but good point. Updated it to `orders`

Comment: So it's a output column name which is internally an `out` parameter - that's your ambiguity

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9622d28a66d309bb4763dbd0a5941ce5

Comment: Read docs here [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html), search for 'ambiguous'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a PL/pgSQL variable, a function parameter or a return parameter with the same name. Avoid ambiguity by qualifying column references with the table name:

```
select pdtproductid
from orders
join product on orders.odrproductid = product.pdtproductid and ...
```