# Column reference is ambiguous in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to simplify this INSERT INTO and keep getting this ambiguous error below. What am I doing wrong here, do I need an alias somewhere that I'm missing?

```
<internal.PGError>: {
                m: {
                    82: "scanRTEForColumn",
                    83: "ERROR",
                    86: "ERROR",
                    67: "42702",
                    77: "column reference \"created_at\" is ambiguous",
                    80: "3082",
                    70: "parse_relation.c",
                    76: "694",
                },
            }
```

Here is the SQL statement I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO delivery_areas
    SELECT
      r.drn_id AS restaurant_drn_id,
      'initial'::algorithm_name AS algorithm_name,
      z.city_drn_id AS city_drn_id,
      ?::geometry AS delivery_area,
      gen_random_uuid() AS drn_id,
      ?::timestamp AS created_at,
      ?::timestamp AS updated_at,
      'custom'::delivery_area_type AS delivery_area_type
    FROM restaurants r
    JOIN neighborhood_zones nz ON (nz.hood_drn_id = r.hood_drn_id)
    JOIN zones z ON (z.drn_id = nz.zone_drn_id)
    WHERE r.drn_id = ?
    GROUP BY restaurant_drn_id, algorithm_name, city_drn_id, created_at, updated_at, delivery_area_type
    ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT delivery_areas_pkey DO UPDATE
    SET
      delivery_area = EXCLUDED.delivery_area,
      delivery_area_type = EXCLUDED.delivery_area_type,
      updated_at = EXCLUDED.updated_at
    RETURNING *
```

Create table statements for the delivery_areas and restaurants:

```
CREATE TYPE algorithm_name as ENUM ('initial');

CREATE TABLE delivery_areas (
  restaurant_drn_id uuid NOT NULL,
  algorithm_name algorithm_name NOT NULL DEFAULT 'initial',
  city_drn_id uuid NOT NULL,
  delivery_area geometry(MultiPolygon,4326) NOT NULL,
  drn_id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (restaurant_drn_id, algorithm_name)
);

CREATE INDEX delivery_areas_algorithm_city_idx on delivery_areas (algorithm_name, city_drn_id);
CREATE INDEX delivery_areas_delivery_area_idx on delivery_areas USING gist(delivery_area);

ALTER TABLE delivery_areas ADD FOREIGN KEY (restaurant_drn_id) REFERENCES restaurants(drn_id);
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE restaurants (
  drn_id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  hood_drn_id uuid NOT NULL,
  delivery_range_delta_m int4 NOT NULL,
  geo_lat double precision NOT NULL,
  geo_long double precision NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: So all the columns in delivery_areas are there in the select statement. And as I can't add an alias on the INSERT INTO statement, what am I missing?

Comment: Qualify all your column references, like `delivery_area` should be `delivery_areas.delivery_area`.  One or more of your column references are resolved by two or more tables and the database is asking you to resolve that ambiguity.

Comment: What is `?::geometry AS delivery_area,` supposed to be ? A placeholder for a positional argument?

Comment: `?::geometry AS delivery_area,` is indeed a placeholder for a positional argument yes

Comment: I added `delivery_areas.` as a prefix before all of the field names on the right inside the select, but now gives me the following error:

`<internal.PGError>: { 77: "syntax error at or near \".\"", ... }`

Comment: @JonArmstrong please see update in the comments

Comment: In what client are you running the query? What does the Postgres log show for an error message?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am running this inside a Go routine. The error is shown in the original post, both before and after the update I posted.

Comment: If it is inside some code then you need to show that code, especially the part of how `?` is dealt with. Also the Postgres server log will have a more useful error message, so look at what it reports and add to your question.

Comment: Update your SQL with the latest changes.  Feel free to add the SQL to show both, if you wish to keep the original.  It's possible you had more than one issue or your edit caused other issues.  *ALSO*, add your create table statements, so that these kinds of errors can be reviewed fully.

Comment: Notice, the error (which I didn't see initially) refers to `created_at`.  Look for that column name in all the related tables.  PG seems to think you have that in other tables.  If so, adjust your `GROUP BY` terms to qualify that column reference.

Comment: Ouch.  :)  That table qualifier doesn't go on the `derived column name`, just on `column references`.   Remove that change and just focus on the column in the error, `created_at`.  Please add your `CREATE TABLE` statements, so the statement and errors can be reviewed more completely.

Comment: @JonArmstrong when you say it goes on `column references`, where do you mean by that? I'm pretty new to this stuff.

Comment: Notice you have a `created_at` column on many of your tables.  Check my answer.  That approach resolves your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice in your `GROUP BY` clause, you have a reference to `created_at`:

```
 GROUP BY restaurant_drn_id, algorithm_name, city_drn_id, created_at, updated_at, delivery_area_type
```

But that column is found in several of your tables.

Prefix that column reference with the correct table, like this:

```
 GROUP BY restaurant_drn_id, algorithm_name, city_drn_id, delivery_areas.created_at, updated_at, delivery_area_type
```

I only guessed which table you wanted to reference.  This will resolve that error, but it might not be the date/timestamp you wanted to group by.

Here's an example of the problem and the solution, and the kind of detail that should be provided when asking this kind of question:

```
CREATE TABLE delivery_areas (
      id          int
    , created_at  timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE restaurants (
      drn_id      int
    , created_at  timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE othertbl (
      id          int
    , created_at  timestamp
);

-- The following generates an error:

INSERT INTO delivery_areas
    SELECT r.drn_id AS restaurant_drn_id
         , current_timestamp AS created_at
      FROM restaurants r
      JOIN othertbl    o
        ON o.id = r.drn_id
     GROUP BY restaurant_drn_id, created_at
;

-- ERROR:  column reference "created_at" is ambiguous
-- LINE 7:      GROUP BY restaurant_drn_id, created_at

-- The following is one way to resolve the error:

INSERT INTO delivery_areas
    SELECT r.drn_id AS restaurant_drn_id
         , current_timestamp AS created_at
      FROM restaurants r
      JOIN othertbl    o
        ON o.id = r.drn_id
     GROUP BY restaurant_drn_id, r.created_at
;
```

Notice the `r.created_at`.  `r` is the qualifier that resolve the ambiguity.

Here's a link to the test case:

[Full working test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fa3f277be6d67289cd824b3fbd572f0a)

Comment: So you have conflicting advice here, am I supposed to be using `r.created_at` or `delivery_areas.created_at`? If I use the latter I get this: `72: "There is an entry for table \"delivery_areas\", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.",`

Comment: @WilliamRose No no.  Did you look at the fiddle link I provided?  `r.created_at` was in the test case I created.  I also referred to your query, added to the top of the answer.  Do you know what `created_at` column you wanted to `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Ahh ok. Yes, I'd like to group by the `delivery_areas` version

Comment: @WilliamRose Perfect.  Then my guess should do the trick, until the next problem is found.

Comment: I used `r.created_at` and that seems to work! Does that mean that the value of `r.created_at` is inserted into the record in `delivery_areas` or the passed in argument value `?::timestamp` as intended?

Comment: @WilliamRose The `SELECT` list determines what is inserted.  The `tbl.created_at` in the `GROUP BY` terms is not inserted, but it is used to determine what rows are selected.  We could chat, if you wish.  I'm not sure you understand this `GROUP BY` behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236216/discussion-between-jon-armstrong-and-william-rose).