# why my query is ambiguous? Knex and Postgres

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I'm building a query, but when execute it trows this error:

```
error: column reference "id" is ambiguous
```

I don't know why, because I'm referencing the table that contains the id

```
let activeComplaints = await knex.select(fieldActiveComplaints)
  .from('mailbox_complaints')
  .innerJoin('superheroes', 'superheroes.id', 'mailbox_complaints.superheroe_id')
  .where('superheroes.id', '=', 'mailbox_complaints.id')
  .orderBy('mailbox_complaints.id', 'desc')
  .limit(pageSize)
  .offset(offset)

let count = knex.count()
  .from('superheroes')
  .innerJoin('superheroes', 'superheroes.id', 'mailbox_complaints.superheroe_id')
  .where('superheroes.id', '=', 'mailbox_complaints.id')
  .then(([query]) => parseInt(query.count, 10))
console.log('activeComplaints==>', activeComplaints)
return Promise.all([activeComplaints, count])
```

And my fieldActiveComplaints looks like this

```
const fieldActiveComplaints = [
'id',
'superheroes.name',
'commentary',
'created_date',
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/sql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 2):

Your `select` uses `fieldActiveComplaints` which looks like this:

```
const fieldActiveComplaints = [
  'id',
  ...
```

There's your unqualified and ambiguous `id`. You have `id` columns in both `superheroes` and `mailbox_complaints` and your joins make them both available to the SELECT clause, PostgreSQL is telling you that it doesn't know which `id` column you want to SELECT.

Qualify everything in `fieldActiveComplaints`:

```
const fieldActiveComplaints = [
  'mailbox_complaints.id',
  'superheroes.name',
  'mailbox_complaints.commentary',
  'mailbox_complaints.created_date',
]
```

so that there's no ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks, but when I put all the table name in fieldActiveComplaints , throws this error 
error: invalid input syntax for type integer: "mailbox_complaints.id"

Comment: Is there any way to get the SQL query that Knex produces? And are you sure `knex.select` takes an array? The examples always use a list of columns.