# column reference "customer_id" is ambiguous

Tags: sql

```
select
    a.order_line,
    a.product_id,
    a.sales,
    b.customer_name,
    b.age
from sales_2015 as a
inner join customer_20_60 as b
   on a.customer_id = b.customer_id 
order by customer_id;
```

I got an error message: column reference "customer_id is ambiguous.
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: prefix it with either a. or b. just like you did in all the other places you referenced that column.

Comment: Better yet don't use a and b, use *meaningful* aliases eg s and c.

Comment: Do you really have a separate sales table for each year?!?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just means that multiple tables have same column name and it doesn't know which to use.

In your case, both - `sales_2015` and `customer_20_60` tables have the column customer_id.

Make sure you use the `a.customer_id` or `b.customer_id` in all the places. Based on the code you have pasted, looks like the only place this is missing is in the order by clause.