# Ambiguous column name 'Created_Date'?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I utilize SQL SSMS. Due to the following, SQL prompts error. After I utilized the same script with many other inner joins the following error remains. I have tried to modify my script, and I keep getting the same messages:

```
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 Ambiguous column name 'Created_Date'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 17 Ambiguous column name 'Created_Date'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 18 Ambiguous column name 'Created_Date'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 19 Ambiguous column name 'Created_Date'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 20 Ambiguous column name 'Created_Date'.
```

[My script]

```
 SELECT 
 rs.Resident_ID, 
 [UserName] = rsdt.First_Name + ' ' + rsdt.Last_Name,
 in.Invoice_Amount,
 in.Due_Date as due,
 in.Created_Date,
 DATEDIFF(day, [Created_Date], Getdate()) as " Number_of_Days ",
 in.Paid_Date as paid,
 in.Description,  
 ar.Payment_Type, 
 ar.Receipt_Descriptions,

 CASE 
     WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Created_Date], Getdate()) Between 90 AND 119 Then '90 days'
     WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Created_Date], Getdate()) Between 120 AND 179 Then '120 days'
     WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Created_Date], Getdate()) Between 180 AND 364 Then '180 days'
     WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Created_Date], Getdate()) >= 365 Then '365+ days'
     END As [Days Outstanding]

   FROM dbo.ar_receipts AS ar
   INNER JOIN dbo.residents AS rs
   ON ar.Resident_ID = rs.Resident_ID 

   INNER JOIN dbo.invoices AS in
   ON ar.Created_Date = in.Created_Date

   WHERE
   DATEDIFF(Day, in.Created_Date, GETDATE ()) > = 90
   AND in.Created_Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -48, GETDATE())
   Order by in.Created_Date
```

Comment: Edited column name, it was just my thought process when originally building my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Created_Date], Getdate()) Between 90 AND 119
```

But the error message is clear: more than one table in your query has a column named `Created_Date`. So, you need to use the table aliases you created to tell SQL Server which one you mean. Presumably it is from `dbo.invoices`, so:

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, in.[Created_Date], Getdate()) Between 90 AND 119
```

Though `in` is also a poor name choice for an alias because, like `double`, it is a reserved word/keyword and at the very least will light up in various editors or, in some contexts, cause a syntax error.

More importantly:

```
DATEDIFF(day, in.[Created_Date], Getdate()) >= 365
```

This is much more efficiently written as:

```
in.Created_Date < DATEADD(DAY, -365, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
```

It's a few extra characters, I know, but that at least has a shot of using an index.

Also, if you traverse the opposite way (oldest category to newest), you don't have to handle the `BETWEEN` scenario at all, because the first scenario that matches will render the rest of the comparisons no-ops:

```
CASE
WHEN in.Created_Date < DATEADD(DAY, -365, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
  THEN '365+ Days'
WHEN in.Created_Date < DATEADD(DAY, -180, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
  THEN '180 Days'
WHEN in.Created_Date < DATEADD(DAY, -120, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
  THEN '120 Days'
WHEN in.Created_Date < DATEADD(DAY, -90,  CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
  THEN '90 Days'
END AS [Days Outstanding]
```

You could also simplify it by:

```
DECLARE @today date = GETDATE();

CASE
WHEN in.Created_Date < DATEADD(DAY, -365, @today)
  THEN '365+ Days'
...
```

Comment: Answer: Your answer was correct, I needed to select the column from specific table, in this case I included "in.Created_Date" on the 'CASE WHEN' and then all data listed correctly. Thank you, very glad to receive your explanation, script logic worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Both dbo.invoices and dbo.ar_receipts have a Created_Date column.

```
   INNER JOIN dbo.invoices AS in
   ON ar.Created_Date = in.Created_Date
```

You need to fully qualify each use of Created_Date as you did above.

For example, `DATEDIFF(day, [Created_Date], Getdate()) as " Number_of_Days "` needs to specify which table's Created_Date. Probably in.Created_Date, but only you can answer that for sure.