# Postgresql column reference is ambiguous

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to call my function but I get this error:

> ERROR:  column reference "list" is ambiguous LINE 3:               SET
> list = ARRAY_APPEND(list, input_list2),

the error is on the second list inside array_append function.

My function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_order(input_id uuid,input_sku text,input_store_id uuid,input_order_date bigint,input_asin text,input_amount int,input_list text[],input_price real,input_list2 text) RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$body$
#variable_conflict use_column
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO orders_summary(id,sku,store_id,order_date,asin,amount,list,price)
            VALUES(input_id,input_sku,input_store_id,to_timestamp(input_order_date / 1000.0),input_asin,input_amount,input_list,input_price) ON CONFLICT(sku,order_date) DO UPDATE
              SET list = ARRAY_APPEND(list, input_list2),
                  amount = amount + input_amount,
                  price = input_price
              WHERE NOT list @> input_list;
END
$body$;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the alias name in the insert query because `list` has two references, one reference in `EXCLUDED.list` and another reference to the column for an update statement.

Please check the below query (I append the alias with name `os` in query):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_order(input_id uuid,input_sku text,input_store_id uuid,input_order_date bigint,input_asin text,input_amount int,input_list text[],input_price real,input_list2 text) RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$body$
#variable_conflict use_column
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO orders_summary as os (id,sku,store_id,order_date,asin,amount,list,price)
            VALUES(input_id,input_sku,input_store_id,to_timestamp(input_order_date / 1000.0),input_asin,input_amount,input_list,input_price) ON CONFLICT(sku,order_date) DO UPDATE
              SET list = ARRAY_APPEND(os.list, input_list2),
                  amount = os.amount + input_amount,
                  price = input_price
              WHERE NOT os.list @> input_list;
END
$body$;
```

Or you can use table name:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_order(input_id uuid,input_sku text,input_store_id uuid,input_order_date bigint,input_asin text,input_amount int,input_list text[],input_price real,input_list2 text) RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$body$
#variable_conflict use_column
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO orders_summary (id,sku,store_id,order_date,asin,amount,list,price)
            VALUES(input_id,input_sku,input_store_id,to_timestamp(input_order_date / 1000.0),input_asin,input_amount,input_list,input_price) ON CONFLICT(sku,order_date) DO UPDATE
              SET list = ARRAY_APPEND(orders_summary.list, input_list2),
                  amount = orders_summary.amount + input_amount,
                  price = input_price
              WHERE NOT orders_summary.list @> input_list;
END
$body$;
```