# INSERT statement gives column reference is ambiguous error when used in Postgres function

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, plpgsql

I have the following function in Postgres for inserting values to a table `employee_leaves` and the table has the following structure

| id[PK] | emp_id[varchar] | lt_id[int] | from_dt[date] | from_session_id[int] | to_dt[Date] | to_session_id[int] | reasons[varchar] | contact_details[varchar] | status[int] | notify_users[jsonb] | pending_with[int] | other_info[jsonb] | created_by[int] | created_on[date] | last_updated_by[int] | last_updated_on[date] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

The function is as follows:

```
-- FUNCTION: company.lib.org.create_edit_employee_leave(json)

-- DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS "company.lib.org".create_edit_employee_leave(json);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "company.lib.org".create_edit_employee_leave(
    params json)
    RETURNS json
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
--select"company.lib.org".create_edit_employee_leave('{"emp_id":292, "lt_id":1, "from_dt":"2022-01-10", "from_session_id":1,"to_dt":"2022-01-11" ,"to_session_id":"2", "reasons":"Leave Reason", "contact_details":"8884514965", "status":1, "notify_users":[1,2,3] ,"pending_with":3, "other_info":"{}"," created_by":"123", "last_updated_by":13, "last_updated_on":"2022-01-20 00:00:00"}');

declare
        emp_id character varying(50);
        query text;
        cond text;  
        response json;
        message character varying(50);

        lt_id smallint;
        from_dt date;
        from_session_id smallint;
        to_dt date;
        to_session_id smallint;
        reasons character varying(1024);
        contact_details character varying(1024);
        status smallint;
        notify_users json;
        pending_with character varying(50);
        other_info json;
        created_by integer;
        created_on timestamp with time zone;
        last_updated_by integer;
        last_updated_on timestamp with time zone;
        
        begin
        emp_id = (params->>'emp_id');
        lt_id = (params->>'lt_id');
        from_dt = (params->>'from_dt');
        from_session_id = (params->>'from_session_id');
        to_dt =  (params->>'to_dt');
        to_session_id = (params->>'to_session_id')::smallint;
        reasons = (params->>'reasons');
        contact_details = (params->>'contact_details');
        status = (params->>'status')::smallint;
        notify_users = COALESCE((params ->> 'notify_users')::jsonb,'{}'::jsonb);
        pending_with=(params->>'pending_with');
        other_info = COALESCE((params ->> 'other_info')::jsonb,'{}'::jsonb);
        created_by = (params->>'created_by')::integer;
        created_on = (params->>'created_on')::date;
        last_updated_by = (params->>'last_updated_by')::integer;
        last_updated_on = (params->>'last_updated_on')::date;
        message = '';
        raise info 'leave_application_id %',emp_id;

        if (params->>'action') = 'C' then
        INSERT INTO "company.lib.org".employee_leaves(
        emp_id, lt_id, from_dt, from_session_id, to_dt, to_session_id, reasons, contact_details, status, notify_users, pending_with, other_info, created_by, created_on, last_updated_by, last_updated_on)
        VALUES (
            emp_id, lt_id, from_dt, from_session_id, to_dt, to_session_id, reasons, contact_details, status, notify_users, pending_with, other_info, created_by, created_on, last_updated_by, last_updated_on
        ) returning emp_id into emp_id;
        end if;
        message = 'New Leave application created successfully';
        
        response = ('{"status": 200, "leave_application_id": "' || emp_id || '", "message":"' || message ||'"}')::json;
    
       return response;
    
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN unique_violation THEN
            response = '{"status": 500, "data": "Unique key violation"}';
        WHEN check_violation THEN
            response = '{"status": 500, "data": "Check violation"}';
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
            response = '{"status": 500, "data": "Check"}';
        WHEN others THEN
            RAISE INFO 'Error Name:%', SQLERRM;
            RAISE INFO 'Error State:%', SQLSTATE;
            response = '{"status": 500, "data": "Unknown exception '|| SQLERRM || '"}'; 
    return response;

    END;
            
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION "company.lib.org".create_edit_employee_leave(json)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Now when I use the following `INSERT` directly, it is working fine

```
INSERT INTO "company.lib.org".employee_leaves(
        emp_id, lt_id, from_dt, from_session_id, to_dt, to_session_id, reasons, contact_details, status, notify_users, pending_with, other_info, created_by, created_on, last_updated_by, last_updated_on)
        VALUES (
            '25506', 1, '2020-01-11', 1, '2020-01-12', 2, 'Leave Reasons', '8884514965', 1, '[25509,25336]', 25509, '{}', 25506, '2022-02-06T06:01:31.025Z', 25506, '2022-02-06T06:01:31.025Z'
        )
```

But when I call function like this,

```
select "company.lib.org".create_edit_employee_leave(
    (
        '{"action":"C","emp_id":"25506","lt_id":1,"from_dt":"2020-01-11","from_session_id":1,"to_dt":"2020-01-12","to_session_id":2,"reasons":"LeaveReasons","contact_details":"8884514965","status":1,"notify_users":["25509","25336"],"pending_with":25509,"other_info":{},"created_by":"25506","created_on":"2022-02-06T06:08:11.531Z","last_updated_by":"25506","last_updated_on":"2022-02-06T06:08:11.531Z"}'
    )::json
```

)

It is giving an error like

```
INFO:  Error Name:column reference "emp_id" is ambiguous
INFO:  Error State:42702
```

As I have shown in the table structure, the column exists in the table and there are no other columns with the same name. However, I have other tables with the same column name and there is a foreign key constraint that refers to the `employee` table and the emp_id in that table. Also, this is an `INSERT` statement. So I am not sure what went wrong here. If someone can tell me what is the error here, that would be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1):

`ambiguous` is caused by having two tables with identical column names like `users.active` and `profile.active` it is clear when your using users or profiles table alone, but if you join them then you have two `active` columns that belong to different tables, so you need to clarify for the query what you are trying to use: is it `users.active` or `profiles.active` explicitly

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is the line

```
returning emp_id into emp_id;
```

which is causing the problem.
You could change the name the local variable in the procedure, insert_emp_id for example.

Answer (score 0):

> By default, PL/pgSQL will report an error if a name in an SQL
> statement could **refer to either a variable or a table column.** You can
> fix such a problem by renaming the variable or column, or by
> qualifying the ambiguous reference, or by telling PL/pgSQL which
> interpretation to prefer.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html

from here> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html.
->> return **text** type.
But you declare
`emp_id character varying(50);`. I am not so sure. I think it's fine. but maybe future will be a issue. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_txt2()
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
declare a varchar(1); 
begin
    RAISE INFO 'Alas we are at the end of our journey';
    a = 'test'::text;
    RAISE INFO 'Alas we are at the end of our journey111';
end;
$BODY$;
```

It will fail.

```
INFO:  Alas we are at the end of our journey
ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(1)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL assignment "a = 'test'::text"
PL/pgSQL function test_txt2() line 5 at assignment
```

> If the expression's result data type doesn't match the variable's data
> type, the value will be coerced as though by an assignment cast (see
> Section 10.4). If no assignment cast is known for the pair of data
> types involved, **the PL/pgSQL interpreter will attempt to convert the
> result value textually**, that is by applying the result type's output
> function followed by the variable type's input function.

further info.https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT

Update: I deep dived a little bit.
From here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/errcodes-appendix.html, you get the error code. Then I searched the postgresql source code.
Then I located the final explanation  page: https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/backend/parser/README;hb=HEAD

[image]