# Error in joining datasets in Superset - column reference "name" is ambiguous

Tags: sql, apache-superset

I have to datasets in my Superset. Let's call one
`prod_company` and the other one `prod_order`. I want to maintain two datasets and join them into a third dataset.

It turns out it is "almost" working building on top of [this PR and some SQL](https://github.com/apache/superset/pull/15241)

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM {{ dataset(38) }}
JOIN {{ dataset(39) }}
ON dataset_38.company_id = dataset_39.company_id
```

Why almost?
Well, that's because both datasets would join `table.company` DB table, and both have column `table.company.name`

So the result is

[image]

And this is where I'm stuck right now.

What are the nuances of building on top of an existing dataset and using that power to join cross-databases and more?

Comment: You can't use * for ambiguous column names; you have to specify what table you want the column names from via aliases in your select statement. This is a common question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/sql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)